# How to echo/print only a certain piece of input?

Tags: php

I want to echo/print only a certain piece of input. For example i have this youtube url http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p963CeTtJVM how would i be able to only echo the last piece of :"p963CeTtJVM" from the input. As far as i know their always 11 symbols.

Code:

```
if (empty($_POST["website"]))
 {$website = "";}
else
 {
 $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
 // check if URL address syntax is valid (this regular expression also allows dashes in   the URL)
 if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$website))
   {
   $websiteErr = "Invalid URL"; 
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it can help you.

```
 <?php

 $url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p963CeTtJVM';

 $urlParts = explode('v=', $url);

 if (count($urlParts) == 2 && isset($urlParts[1])) {
     echo "youtube code : {$urlParts[1]}";
 } else {
     echo "Invalid Youtube url.";
 }
```

Comment: That's good if you don't mind also catching the other parameters if they're after `v` as if they're part of the same value. So with `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12345678901&hax=foobar` you get `12345678901&hax=foobar`.

Answer (score 1):

```
list ($void, $query_string) = split('?', $url); // or list(,$qs)
parse_str($query_string, $data);
var_dump($data);
```

For this specific string substr($str, -11) will take the last 11 chars, but that doesn't include other tags. Check out [parse_str](http://www.php.net/parse_str), it will probably save you a headache in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You can use substr method to return part of a string.

Comment: Exactly. Just be sure with the length of the returned string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the explode function to seperate the video ID and the rest of the link like this:

```
$array = explode("=", $website);
echo $array[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

This [parses the URL into its component parts](https://www.php.net/parse_url), then [parses the query string into an associative array](https://www.php.net/parse_str).

```
$url = parse_url($url);

parse_str($url['query'], $params);

$v = $params['v'];
```